# Pass in logic in react on rails props

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm new to react on rails and I am looking for a way to pass in rails logic into the react props. Currently, I'm getting the following error: `No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]`
The error is justified because the `current_user` is `nil`.
I have passed the props into the `react_component` in the following way:

```rb
<%= react_component("Header", props: { 
                                        signout_path: session_path(current_user),
                                        current_user: {
                                          username: current_user.username,
                                          email: current_user.email
                                        } 
                                      }) %>
```

When I `login` the `current_user` is not `nil` and the `prop` works, but as soon as I logout from the app, the `current_user` is `nil` and I get the above mentioned error.
My `current_user` method in the rails looks like this:

```rb
def current_user
  return nil unless session[:user_id]
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end
```

Is there a way to add in some logic, so that only when the `current_user` is not `nil` the prop gets passed? Somewhat like:

```rb
<%= react_component("Header", props: { 
                                        unless current_user.nil?
                                          signout_path: session_path(current_user),
                                          current_user: {
                                            username: current_user.username,
                                            email: current_user.email
                                          }
                                        end
                                      }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I came with an approach and I'm not sure if this is the proper way.

```rb
<% if current_user.nil? %>
  <%= react_component("Header", props: { 
                                        root_path: root_path, 
                                        signup_path: new_user_path, 
                                        signin_path: new_session_path
                                        }) %>
<% else %>
  <%= react_component("Header", props: { 
                                        root_path: root_path,
                                        signup_path: new_user_path, 
                                        signin_path: new_session_path,
                                        signout_path: session_path(current_user),
                                        current_user: {
                                          username: current_user.username,
                                          email: current_user.email
                                        } 
                                      }) %>
<% end %>
```

The code works as expected. If you have a better approach, please answer.